# How to fail task flow in informatica using windows batch script

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud

We are calling a windows batch script in the informatica cloud for preprocessing and post processing commands. but we are unable to pass the exit 1 message to informatica to fail the task. Windows batch script is working fine separately but when the script fails, informatica not able to understand the exit code and always pass the script. In short, informatica task always pass, irrespective whether script pass or fail. Please help !

Comment: In such scenarios its safe to use event wait. Create an empty file if your processess succeeded. So, i think you need to create a workflow(and import that in infa cloud) then task, task flow and then you can run that with event wait. This is just my 2 cents.

Comment: Let me give you brief idea about what i am trying to do. Actually i have take the latest date from control table and compare with the system date. if its not matching then fail the script as well as informatica task but i am able to fail the script not task. informatica task always goes to success.

Comment: In infa clould you have a function called ABORT('msg'). You can create a mapping as pre-process to check if control date and system date matching or not and abort accordingly.

Comment: @Koushik:- thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Control table comparison with the system date is post processing activity?

Answer (score 0):

Pre- or post-session commands can be written  to start FTP/SFTP scripts or stored procedures, rename or archive files, or run post-processing commands. Could you try the same using stored procedures and add exception handling when comparison fails.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for Informatica Cloud Data Integration.

Instead of using pre-sess or post-sess commands, the team can use a command task. In your windows batch script, send the error code as 1 if you want to fail the command task

```
exit /B 1
```

Then in the Advanced Taskflow, enable the property, "Fail task if any script fails"
This property will ensure that the command task fails in the Advanced Taskflow if the exit code from the batch script is 1

[image: Informatica Advanced Taskflow Command Task]

Hope this helps. Cheers..!!

Answer (score -1):

You have to enable a property "Fail task if any command fails" in the command task for Informatica to recognize the script/command failure and fail the command task. Please refer below snapshot

[image]

Comment: We are working on informatica cloud and there is no such option is on cloud.